# jQuery datatables filtering not working after column re-order

Tags: jquery, datatables

Using jquery datatables I have filtering via dropdownlists in the footer.
Problem I am running into is that when a column is re-ordered the filter stops working and will throw up one of those cryptic errors saying to see http://datatables.net/tn/4 for more info (which did not bring me any closer to solving this problem).

```js
var datatableOpts = {
        "dom": 'CRT<"clearfix"><"pull-left"l><"pull-right"f>r<"horizontal-scroll"t><"pull-left"i><"pull-right"p><"clearfix">',
        "colReorder": {
            "reorderCallback": function () { }
        },
        "stateSave": true,
        "stateLoadCallback": function (settings) {
            return reportJson;
        },
        "initComplete": function () {
            $(this.api().columns()[0]).each(function (i, item) {
                var column = $("#reportTable").DataTable().columns(item)
                var currentFilter = $("#reportTable").DataTable().columns(i).search()[0]
                var select = $("<select><option value=''>No Filter</option></select>")
                    .appendTo($(column.footer()).empty())
                    .on("change", function () {
                        var val = $(this).val()

                        //I added the following 2 rows as on initialize the column the filter was being applied against was set and after re-order, that columns index would then be different..... didn't solve the issue.
                        var index = $(this).parent("th").index();
                        column = $("#reportTable").DataTable().columns(index);

                        column
                            .search(val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false)
                            .draw();
                    });

                $(_.uniq(column.data()[0])).sort().each(function (d, j) {
                    var value = removeSpanTags(j).trim()

                    if ($(select).find("option[value='" + HtmlEncode(value) + "']").length >= 1) {
                        return;
                    }

                    var opt = $("<option></option>").attr("value", value).text(value)

                    if (currentFilter != "" && currentFilter == value) {
                        opt.attr("selected", "selected")
                    }

                    opt.appendTo(select)
                });
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: How do you reorder the columns?

Comment: Sorry, when I was reformatting after the initial paste i must have deleted the first line in the init options: "dom" which has the reorder "RT"